# Ansible inventory plugin `community.general.nmap` states that it can run in a playbook. Is there a usage example of this?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

The plugin found here (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmap_inventory.html) states "To use it in a playbook, specify: `community.general.nmap`".

I have not seen how this could be accomplished.  I have the it working as a general inventory plugin, but I am curious if it can actually be triggered in a playbook task.  For reference I did try this:

```
- name: Test Inventory
  community.general.nmap:
    address: 192.168.0.0/24
```

But that just says that the module does not exist.  So can it actually be run in a playbook, or is this an errant remark?  If it can, could I have an example, please?

I am running `ansible [core 2.13.3]` and version `6.4.0` of `community.general.nmap`.

Comment: It is an `inventory plugin` not a `module`. It's a documentation error: `To use it in a playbook, specify ...` Of course, you can't use an inventory plugin in a playbook. See the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmap_inventory.html#examples).

Comment: ... as you already mentioned "_... I have the it working as a general inventory plugin_", it is an [Inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general), we can see that there is no `nmap` module in the [`plugins/modules`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/plugins/modules) directory (nor is it a [`lookup plugin`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/plugins/lookup)).

It looks like that is simply erroneous documentation.